# System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to delete a selected gridview row using LINQ (No
LINQDataSource).

When the selection is changed, the detailsview binding is changed
also. I can add a new entry to the database, but when I added this
code to a delete button inside the updatePanel, I got an exception:

```
try
{           
    var query = from i in db.QuestionModules 
                where i.QuestionModuleID == QuestionModuleID 
                select i;

    QuestionModule o = query.First();
    db.QuestionModules.DeleteOnSubmit(o);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed. at
System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
failureMode) at
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

I've had this problem for about a week, and no matter what I do, it is
still there, and the record doesn't get deleted.

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 71):

OK - it looks as though (in my case at least) the answer was to set *all* non primary-key column's UpdateCheck property to *Never* in the DBML file. Doing this immediately cured the problem of "Row not found or changed".

Given the rumour that Microsoft are moth-balling Linq-To-Sql in favor of Entity Framework, one wonders whether these sorts of bugs will be fixed?

Comment: +1 as it worked. can any one shed. some light on the implications of this. Blog post or otherwise would be great. Thanks.

Comment: As alluded to in Mark's other answer, this works because some types (such as `datetime2` with high precision) are not marshaled correctly between the server and client and Linq-To-SQL's [optimistic concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) feature thinks the loss of precision in the erroneous marshaling is a sign that the database updated its value and aborts the action. Flipping it to `Never` prevents the optimistic concurrency checking so it (correctly in this case) succeeds.

Comment: this was my issue - the linq query produced contains EVERY single field in the WHERE clause during the UPDATE statement.  so by the time we `.SubmitChanges()` the UPDATE wouldn't happen based on the now outdated WHERE - so it threw this exception.  We removed the update checks on these fields to solve..

Answer (score 63):

You are getting this error quite possibly because one of your fields has something different in the Linq To SQL designer and in the actual database.

In my case, it was because one of the fields was nullable in the database and not nullable in the designer, making it nullable in the designer as well solved the problem immediately.

Comment: Missmatch in the DBML and database was my problem to.

Comment: Right, i thought so. Imagine a recommendation to set "all" columns to some value has more votes :(

Comment: Yeah, this is the true answer.

Comment: yes. my case was same as your. +1 for saving my time!

Comment: urgh, that was so obvious. setting the column to accept null values fixed it!

Answer (score 23):

I got around this issue, by making sure to refresh my object immediately before updating it.  I do this with the KeepChanges option.

```
    db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepChanges, employee);
```

Comment: This seems to have resolved my issues thanks! Another service can concurrently update this record and I needed to refresh it before submitting.

Comment: Yeah! it works for me too! first I tried to delete the table from `dbml` and re-drag it, but it didn't work. this was the solution.

Answer (score 15):

I'm having the same problem, and came across [this blog](http://forums.asp.net/t/1016914.aspx), which basically states that Linq-To-Sql has got a problem in it's optimistic concurrency where:

1. High precision datetime fields are used. The solution is to set UpdateCheck to never for that column your DBML file
2. GridView columns which are set to invisible are accessing a property on the data object (this second reason makes no sense, but it seems to be all the rage on that blog).

I haven't tried these solutions yet, but will post back here once I have.

Comment: OK - I've just tried setting all Date column's UpdateCheck to Never... no joy, I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: I had the same problem with some datetime field update: changing the UpdateCheck value solved the problem.

Comment: +1 I had this problem, with a `float` field on the SQL DB, which I had mapped to a `float` (single) type in C#.  When I changed the type to `double` the problem went away.  But it was this answer of yours that tipped me off - so THANK YOU!

Comment: +1 when I added 2 more columns of Date type the linq started to give this exception.
then setting the property attribute UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never the problem was solved.

Comment: UpdateCheck=Never solved it for me but I only had to do it for the column I have changed

Comment: Thanks, UpdateCheck never is fixing the issue, now my entity class column definition is looking like below, looks like issue is with datetime columns and optimistic lock. The fix is to remove datetime fields from optimistic lock.

[Column(UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
public DateTime? ScheduledOn { get; set; }

Answer (score 13):

The problem could be also simply that the DBML definition of the table is not consistent with the status of the Database definition. I just removed the DBML model and inserted it again from the database, and it worked.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: This worked for me. I tried manually checking and adjusting the DBML table and although it looked the same, only removing and re-dragging the table into the DBML worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Seemed to work for my situation also. I was building an in memory, never before submitted row which had several foreign key relationships to rows in other tables. The InsertOnSubmit seemed to work but a subsequent DeleteOnSubmit was giving me that row not found error. I was not populating every field in the row I submitted so I don't know if that had anything to do with it but marking all of the main table's non-primary key columns eliminated the error message.

One further thought: I take it that marking a column's UpdateCheck policy as 'Never' means that it is not used as the basis for optimistic concurency checking. This would imply that two users could write over a given row with different data in any such column and the conflicts would not be detected...meaning the last user to submit the row would overwrite the values of the previous users submission. I gathered from various online reading that one partial solution to this is to use the Refresh method immediately before submission to sync up any changes. Of course with no pesimistic lock on the row there is no guarantee that the row won't still be changed between the Refresh and the Submit but in most scenarios involving large databases this would be rare.

Update: On further review I think I have discovered a scenario that may be affecting others so I thought I would share it just in case. It turns out that at least part of the trouble I have been having with SQL LINQ is related to triggers. It appears that if you submit a row using SQL LINQ and your DBA has triggers designed to write information to some columns in that row then the SQL LINQ model will by default 'Always' determine that the row has been changed since your last write of it. I was submitting partially populated rows and our DBA's triggers are filling in some columns so that when I attempted to further modify the row in our code it sensed a change conflict based on the columns populated by the trigger. I am investigating now the best way to handle this but changing these trigger populated fields to use an UpdateCheck policy of 'When Changed' or 'Never' worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a case of mismatched column definitions. Just remove the table from `.dbml`and re-add. Make sure to change `auto generate value property = true` for columns that have auto generated data such as Primary Keys or datetime columns.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar changeconflictexception/"Row not found or changed" when updating a row.
Solved it by re-adding the tabbles in the dbml.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had was that I had a DateTime type in the .net framework, but our database field was of DateTime2 type, which is higher precision datatype.  So when we would submit changes the date fields of the object vs. the DB was just a few nanoseconds off which would cause the concurrency error.  This happened when we migrated to a newer MSSQL version and it converted our DateTime fields to DateTime2.

So in our code where we had:

```
    Obj.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now()
```

We changed it to:

```
    Obj.DateUpdated = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

So check your datatypes, especially your date fields, if you get this error after making an upgrade and or migration.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that no columns contain `null` values in the related table (i.e. the table to be updated).

Comment: How in the world would anyone use L2S without any nullability on any DB field?

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just changed all the NULL values to something that should be the default, even though the db should support NULL in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Under:

```
QuestionModule o = query.First();
```

You have to add the following command:

```
db.QuestionModule.Attach(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by executing databind() on the gridview and datasource during updatepanel postback.

```
    protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
        LinqDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
```

I refresh updatepanel each time my selection index changes and it was able to resolve the conflicts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also - if you're calling the selecting method for the linqdatasource and setting  e.result manually, make sure you're including any foreignkey values as well.

Nothing else worked for me but this.

Answer (score 0):

The way i fixed it was: First I update the database, then I set the new values for the grid as

```
e.Keys["ColumnOne"] ="new value"
e.Keys["ColumnTwo"] ="new value"
```

All this was done under the `GridView_RowUpdating` event.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my scenario for anybody who may have this issue.

We use a custom T4 against our Linq to SQL dbml. We basically just modified the original  get/set of string properties to automatically trim and set null.

```
        get { return _OfficiantNameMiddle.GetValueOrNull(); }
        set 
        {
            value = value.GetValueOrNull();
            if (_OfficiantNameMiddle != value) 
            {
                _IsDirty = true;
                OnOfficiantNameMiddleChanging(value);
                SendPropertyChanging("OfficiantNameMiddle");
                _OfficiantNameMiddle = value;
                SendPropertyChanged("OfficiantNameMiddle");
                OnOfficiantNameMiddleChanged();
            }
        }
```

Legacy data in our database had some leading/trailing spaces so any concurrency check on these columns failed to result in a match (it was comparing the trimmed value against the non-trimmed database value). It was really easy to profile SQL, grab the SQL and start commenting out the items in the WHERE clause until it started returning a row during the concurrency check.

Luckily, we have a LastUpdatedOn field in our tables that is automatically set via OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction).

```
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (action == System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction.Insert)
        {
            CreatedBy = CurrentUserID;
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            LastUpdatedBy = CreatedBy;
            LastUpdatedOn = CreatedOn;
        }
        else if (action == System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction.Update)
        {
            LastUpdatedBy = CurrentUserID;
            LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

In order to bypass the problem, we just set the concurrency check to Never on all columns except the Primary Key columns and LastUpdatedOn column. This worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and although deleting and re-adding the DBML table/class helped some users, for me it was a bit different since I'm using WCF with detached entity and a ListView on the client.

If I used the .Attach(entity) it failed - "Row not found or changed"
But when using .Attach(entity, original) it works every time

```
public void DeleteTask(Task task)
    {
        TwoDooDataContext db = new TwoDooDataContext();
        db.Tasks.Attach(task,GetTaskByID(task.ID));
        db.Tasks.DeleteOnSubmit(task);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an enum column (mapped to a varchar) which caused the problem, so I had to pass update check to never.

Answer (score 0):

As @dherrin79 indicated, this can be caused because of a precision variance between the database and the code.  For me, the issue was the database column was supposed to be decimal(10,2), but it had been created as decimal(18,0).  This was for a money field, so perhaps I should have used the money column type.

So, I saved a dollar amount, like $3.14 to it, but the decimal was stripped.  This resulted in the database value being changed and not matching the value in C#.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For us the problem started when we switched to DateTime2 on the SQL Server side. Just marking fields with Column(DbType = "DateTime2") did not help. 
So, what happened was that initially on the database side we declared our columns as DateTime2(3) to be "backward compatible" with the old DateTime type and everything seemed to work fine until we noticed that when we use SQL-2-Linq we get the "Row not found or changed" exception in the updates of those date fields. To make the quite-long story short the solution was to do 2 things:

1. Mark the columns with [Column(DbType = "DateTime2(3)", CanBeNull =
   false)] to match the database declaration. AND
2. Trim the extra precision digits from the properties in setters like so:

`[Column(DbType = "DateTime2(3)", CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime ModifiedAt {
        get => _modifiedAt;
        set => _modifiedAt = value.AddTicks(-(value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond));
    }`