# Linq Update Query generates Where 0 = 1?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am setting the Address of a class generated by Linq 2 Sql and when I try to SubmitChanges(), the sql query it generates is:

```
Update Users
Set Address = @po
Where 0 = 1
--@po: Input VarChar (Size = 15; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [123 45th Street]
```

I can't figure out why I am getting Where 0 = 1.

Comment: Can you post the Linq code as well please?

Comment: Related exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805968

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can happen when your object model differs from the database **even by one property**.

Is it possible that Address is nullable in the database and not in your model, or the other way around?  Or the type differs, say ntext vs nvarchar, etc?  In some cases it can be another unrelated property...think back to the last change to the database or model you made, make sure that's in sync.

Comment: I will take a look, but is it a difference between one property on the table I am trying to update or the whole database?

Comment: @Xaisoft - Almost always related to the table you're updating, but I've seen stranger things happen.

Comment: +1. May help others: Had this error when updating a row which was retrieved with a null value in a column which was incorrectly declared in the data context as not nullable.

Comment: This was my error as well. I had a field's nullable property flipped. But why would this cause an invalid where clause? Throw an error at me Linq, I can take it. But don't generate an invalid where clause just for fun. Makes it tough to track down.