# DeleteOnSubmit - Row not found or changed

Tags: asp.net

```
//SelectUtilitiesCheckbox is bound to a complete list of the Utilitie_companies table
foreach (ListItem x in SelectUtilitiesCheckBox.Items)
{
    Select_Utility SU = rows.Where(r => r.Utility_Id == Convert.ToInt32(x.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
    bool initialValue = SU != null;

    if (x.Selected == true && initialValue == false)
    {
        // New qualification added so save it
        Select_Utility NewSelectUtility = new Select_Utility();
        NewSelectUtility.WorkId = tempWorkSiteId;
        NewSelectUtility.Utility_Id = System.Convert.ToInt32(x.Value);

        context.Select_Utilities.InsertOnSubmit(NewSelectUtility);
    }
    else if (x.Selected == false && initialValue == true)
    {
        // Removed old qualification so remove it in the database
        context.Select_Utilities.DeleteOnSubmit(SU);
    }
}

context.SubmitChanges();
```

My Q being - USING LINQ - Insert on submit works fine, but when I try to use deleteOnSubmit I get an

> ERROR: ChangeConflictEception was unhandled by user code - Row not found or changed.

When it reaches context.submit BUT using breakpoit 'Su' in context.Select_Utilities.DeleteOnSubmit(SU); contains the correct record to deletee

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to...

[System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805968/system-data-linq-changeconflictexception-row-not-found-or-changed)

I have solved the issue.

The problem being: one of my fields in the Db was nullable but not nullable in the DBML file. Changing records to suit solved the issue.